# (Hive, SQL) - How to sort a list of string inside a column?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, cloudera, impala

I have a big data problem in Hive (SQL).

```
SELECT genre, COUNT(*) AS unique_count
FROM table_name
GROUP BY genre
```

which gives result like:

```
genre           |   unique_count
----------------------------------
Romance,Crime,Drama,Law | 1560
Crime,Drama,Law,Romance | 895
Law,Romance,Crime,Drama | 942
Adventure,Action        | 3250
Action,Adventure        | 910
```

What I want is to sort the elements in genre ASC|DESC and get results like

```
genre           |   unique_count
----------------------------------
Crime,Drama,Law,Romance | 3397
Action,Adventure        | 4160
```

I could do this in Python but I have over `200 Million` rows of data. I'm not aware of any reasonable way I can move that data.
So how can I achieve this?

Comment: Fix your data structure.  Storing lists of things in comma-delimited strings just causes problems.  If you didn't know this already, you have now learned why this is a bad idea.

Comment: Gordon, I actually do know that but when join a company with existing data, there's little you can do than to massage the messy data. right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select      concat_ws(',',sort_array(split(genre,','))) as genre
           ,count(*)                                    as unique_count

from        table_name

group by    concat_ws(',',sort_array(split(genre,',')))
```

Comment: Prefect. Thank you!